# Related Rates: Two sides of a triangle are 6 m and 8 m in length and the angle between them is increasing at a rate of 0.06 rad/s.

Tags: calculus

Two sides of a triangle are 6 m and 8 m in length and the angle between them is increasing at a rate of 0.06 rad/s. Find the rate at which the area of the triangle is increasing when the angle between the sides of fixed length is π/3 rad

Also, I have been using the following template below; however, I do not understand how they computed 63/25? I have used this solved calculation (below) as a template; yet with my problem that I want to solve in the "title", I keep getting 14.4/20?

Help welcomed. [image]

Answer (score -1):

$42 \times 0.06 = 42 \times \frac {6}{100} = 42 \times \frac {3}{50}=\frac {126}{50}=\frac {63}{25}$

You should get $24 \times 0.06 = 24 \times \frac {6}{100} = 24 \times \frac {3}{50}=\frac {72}{50}=\frac {36}{25}$

This is what you should have instead of the $\frac {63}{25}$ in their example. You then need to go on to multiply by $\frac 1 2$.

You have $\frac {14.4}{20}$ as your final answer or the shaded part?

If the final answer, then all is well. $\frac {14.4}{20} = \frac {144}{200}= \frac {18}{25}$

Comment: What real property of numbers are you following? why are you not allowed to multiply 42 by 0.06.

Comment: 36/25 is not the right answer.

Comment: Two sides of a triangle are 6 m and 8 m in length and the angle between them is increasing at a rate of 0.06 rad/s. Find the rate at which the area of the triangle is increasing when the angle between the sides of fixed length is π/3 rad

Comment: The answer is not right.

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: So I have to multiply 36/25 by 1/2?

Comment: The answer is incorrect-